# Is OxyPlot.Wpf compatible with .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, oxyplot

Does `OxyPlot.Wpf` work on `.NET Core`?

My application uses `.NET Framework 4.8`.  I am considering switching to `.NET Core 3.1.5` which was released in 2020 June.

Note OxyPlot has an assembly called `OxyPlot.Core` but it has nothing to do with `.NET Core` from what information I have gathered. `OxyPlot.Core` is "the core library... you also need to add a platform-specific OxyPlot package". This makes it seem that `OxyPlot.Wpf` depends upon `OxyPlot.Core` and in fact if you try to uninstall `OxyPlot.Core` the error will be "unable to uninstall OxyPlot.Core.2.0.0 because OxyPlot.Wpf.2.0.0 depends on it".  The online documentation does not seem to tell you this but fortunately NuGet will prevent the uninstall.

This means `OxyPlot.Core` is the core of OxyPlot and its existence does not necessarily tell you anything explicit about .NET compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say yes it is compatible. Based on the nuget link https://www.nuget.org/packages/OxyPlot.Wpf

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Think you Will find OxyPlot works fine with Wpf .NET Core .. but I cannot say the same for a Winforms .NET Core project I have; at the present time I am having (the usual) enormous difficulty in making it work